# TileMap Collision

Tags: java, opengl, 2d, lwjgl

How do you do proper collision with a tilemap?

This is my current solution:

```
    int topTileX = ((tileMap.xOffs - x) - 32 - 1) / Tile.TILE_SIZE;
    int topTileY = ((tileMap.yOffs - y) - 32 - 1) / Tile.TILE_SIZE;

    int bottomTileX = ((tileMap.xOffs - x) - 1) / Tile.TILE_SIZE;
    int bottomTileY = ((tileMap.yOffs - y) - 1) / Tile.TILE_SIZE;

    int leftTileX = ((tileMap.xOffs - x) - 32-1) / Tile.TILE_SIZE;
    int leftTileY = ((tileMap.yOffs - y) - 32-1) / Tile.TILE_SIZE;

    int rightTileX = ((tileMap.xOffs - x)-1) / Tile.TILE_SIZE;
    int rightTileY = ((tileMap.yOffs - y)-1) / Tile.TILE_SIZE;


    if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_W)) {
        if (!tileMap.getLayer(0)[Math.abs(topTileY+1)][Math.abs(topTileX)].isBlocked()) {
            tileMap.yOffs++;
        }
    } 
    if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_S)) {
        if (!tileMap.getLayer(0)[Math.abs(bottomTileY-1)][Math.abs(bottomTileX)].isBlocked()) {
            tileMap.yOffs--;
        }
    } 
    if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_D)) {
        if (!tileMap.getLayer(0)[Math.abs(rightTileY)][Math.abs(rightTileX-1)].isBlocked()) {
            tileMap.xOffs--;
        }
    }
    if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_A)) {
        if (!tileMap.getLayer(0)[Math.abs(leftTileY)][Math.abs(leftTileX+1)].isBlocked()) {
            tileMap.xOffs++;
        }
    }
```

But with this the player would get stuck in corners and some tiles wouldn't even work. tell me the proper way to check for collision and handle the collision without the playing getting stuck and such.

Comment: From what I can tell, you seem to be computing the player's tile coordinates based on pixel (?) coordinates. That seems very fragile; I would recommend storing the tile that the player is on instead.

Comment: But the only way I can do this is do compute what tile he is on from xOffs - x / Tile.TILE_SIZE, How else would i get the tile he is on

Comment: What I'm recommending (and what most games do) is store the tile coordinate that the player is on, and compute the pixel coordinates from that. You seem to be doing it the other way around.

Comment: Can you give me an example? Im not quite understanding.